# Adding an unknown number of files' content to an array with Gulp.js

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to add the contents of a unknown number of files to an array with Gulp. Like so:

```
var data = [];

return gulp.src('data/**')
    .pipe(/*...*/); // Here I'd like to add all content of all files in `data` 
                    // to my data array.
```

I'm at a loss as I don't know how to tackle the synchronous nature of node. **How would I be able to overcome this?**

Comment: Maybe it's as easy as reading a files contents and storing that into my array. Still don't know how to...

Comment: You are meaning the Asynchronous nature of node? gulp is streams...

Comment: I always confuse myself with asynchronous and synchronous. :s

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't totally answer your question, but this plugin looks like a good place to start:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-tap

EDIT: Something like this maybe?

```
.pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
    data.push(file.content);
}))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried tap. It's a handy little gulp package. Wasn't able to tackle my problem though. :)

Comment: That code snippet wouldn't put the contents of each of the files into your array?

Comment: It puts 4 x `undefined` in my array.